# Listen to document changes on Firestore and create a stream of objects for StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I have the following function which gets a product document from Firestore, to be used with a **FutureBuilder**:

```
Future<Product> getProduct(String productId) async {
    var ref = _db.collection('products').doc(productId);
    var snapshot = await ref.get();
    return Product.fromJson(snapshot.data() ?? {});
  }
```

I can I achieve the same functionality, but with a **StreamBuilder** so that the build method will be called any time there's a change to the document?

```
Stream<Product> listenToProduct(String productId) {
?
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, this seems to work:

```
Stream<Product> listenToProduct(String productId) {
return _db.collection('products')
    .doc(productId)
    .snapshots()
    .map((snapshot) => Product.fromJson(snapshot.data()!));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Stream<Product> listenToProduct(String productId) {
   return _db.collection('products').doc(productId).snapshots()
          .listen((event) => Product.fromJson(event.data() ?? {});
}
```

Something similar to that.

Comment: This throws compile errors

Comment: I haven't tested it myself but changed `Product.fromJson(snapshot.data() ?? {});` to `Product.fromJson(event.data() ?? {});` as event is the argument name in listen method.

Comment: Still throws the following error: A value of type 'StreamSubscription<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>' can't be returned from the method 'listenToProduct' because it has a return type of 'Stream<Product>'.

Comment: You might have to use StreamTransformer to transform the data into Stream<Product> @user6097845

Comment: can you provide a code snippet?